# Print integers in a Matrix coming in order without duplicates

Tags: matlab

I have several `matrices <1x1000>` containing integers such as:

```
matrix = [0,0,0,0,0,30,30,30,40,40,50,50,50,40,0,0,0,30,30,30]
```

I want to print (`disp`, and later `plot`) them like this: **30,40,50,40,30**. Basically ignore the duplicates if they come after each other.

Another example:

`matrix = [0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,50,50,50,50,10,10,10,50,50]` shall give: **10,50,10,50**

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: please give an small example of your actual matrix data using actual MATLAB syntax e,g, `matrix = [0,0,0,0,30,30,30,40]` or `matrix= {[0,0,0,30,30,40,40], [0,0,30,30,30,40,30,30,0,0]}` etc

Comment: how is the intention in case of something like `[10 0 10 20]`? There may be two solutions: `[10 20]` and `[10 10 20]`

Comment: Shall be [10 10 20]

Comment: You received many ideas how to solve your question. Some of them may require further edits to fit your needs, but I think this is acceptable. If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Result = 0;
% loop over all nonzero values in matrix
for Element = matrix
    if Element == Result(end)
        % skip if equal
        continue
    else
        % add new value
        Result(end+1) = Element;
    end
end
% discard zero entries
Result = Result(Result ~= 0);
```

Comment: Stupid question but how do I print it? disp(Result)?

Comment: @J.Smith type `Result` without `;`

Comment: @J.Smith `disp(sprintf('%u\t\t', Result))` also a possibility

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
[~,c]=find([NaN diff(matrix)]);
output=matrix(c);
output = output(output~=0)
```

and to plot the output, simply use: `plot(output)`

Answer (score 1):

All solutions provided so far use either loops or the function `find` which are both inefficient.
Just use matrix indexation:

```
[matrix((matrix(1:end-1)-matrix(2:end))~=0), matrix(end)]

ans =

0    30    40    50    40     0     30
```

By the way in your example are you discarting the `0`s even if they come in repeated sequences?

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the output matrix `um` then

```
um(1) = matrix(1);
j = 1;
for i=2: length(matrix)
  % Ignore repeating numbers
  if (um(j) ~= matrix(i))
    j = j + 1;
    um(j) = matrix(i);
  end
end

% Remove zeros
um = um(um~=0);
```